# launch job from step in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, transactional

I am trying to launch a job from inside a step (the *execute* method of a class implementing the interface *Tasklet*).

Obviously i received the exception

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository*

How to make a spring batch step not transactional?

Does anyone have a solution to my main need of launching a job from inside a step?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

> How to make a spring batch step not transactional?

You can set a [`ResourcelessTransactionManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/support/transaction/ResourcelessTransactionManager.html) on your step. Think of it as a NoOp transaction manager.

> Does anyone have a solution to my main need of launching a job from inside a step?

The [JobStep](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobStep.html) is specifically designed for this use case. It is a `Step` implementation that delegates to a `Job`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Mahmoud!
I was trying to configure a NOT_SUPPORTED transaction propagation for the tasklet through annotation configuration: it was needed to do that in xml configuration file where I configured spring context.